# Permissions to files after upload with php

Tags: php, file, iis, windows-server-2012-r2

I having a problem which when files are uploaded to there folder with PHP they don't have any permissions to then view them on my website.

I'm using IIS and the IIS permission doesn't get set when the folder has the correct permissions. 
Because what I'm doing it uploading the file location to my database then using that to display it on page if i change the file permissions it works fine but i would have to do this every time something is uploaded to my server.

Thanks,

Comment: Did you upload the file using PHP? like someone push it through a form in a web. or you upload the file using FTP/something else?

Comment: I uploaded with PHP through a form.

Comment: Hmm, that's weird. it should have the same owner with the one running the PHP script(IIS Server). maybe you can try using `chown`/`chmod` to change the file permission everytime an upload is made. http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php

Comment: You should be able to add code in your script that will change the permissions for you on every upload.  I'm not familiar with how to do it for IIS, but with PHP on Linux, you can use chmod() and chgrp().  There is info in the manual about those.